# Classes and Objects. Summing the data

Tags: c++, class, object

So here's the question:

Create a 'DISTANCE' class with:

1. data members: feet and inches
2. member functions:
   • Input to input distance
   • Output to output distance
   • Add to add two distance objects

Write an application program with a main function to create 2 objects of DISTANCE
class, namely d1and d2. Then using object d3, sum the objects d1 and d2 and store the
sum in d3 and then display the object d3.

I tried to do it but i'm getting error messages. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my program? I'm learning it on my own. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you. :)

Here's my code for the .h file:

```
#ifndef DISTANCE_H
#define DISTANCE_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Distance
{
private:
double feet_1,feet_2;
double inches_1,inches_2;

public:
double inputfeet1(double feet1);
double inputfeet2(double feet2);
double inputinch1(double inch1);
double inputinch2(double inch2);
double sumFeet(double feets);
double sumInch(double inches);
};

#endif // DISTANCE_H
```

This one is for the .cpp file

```
#include "../include/Distance.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double Distance::inputfeet1(double feet1)
{
if(feet1 < 0)
{
    cout<<"Cannot be less than zero. Default value of 0 is used.";
}
else
{
    feet_1 = feet1;
}
}

double Distance::inputfeet2(double feet2)
{
if(feet2 < 0)
{
    cout<<"Cannot be less than zero. Default value of 0 is used.";
}
else
{
    feet_2 = feet2;
}

double Distance::inputinch1(double inch1)
{
if(inch1 < 0)
{
    cout<<"Cannot be less than zero. Default value of 0 is being used.";
}
else
{
    inch_1 = inch1;
}

}

double Distance::inputinch2(double inch2)
{
if(inch2 < 0)
{
    cout<<"Cannot be less than zero. Default value of 0 is being used.";
}
else
{
    inch_2 = inch2;
}
}

double Distance::sumFeet()
{
return feet_1 + feet_2;
}

double Distance::sumInch()
{
return inches_1 + inches_2;
}

}
```

And this one is the main.cpp

```
#include "include/Distance.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
Distance d1,d2,d3;
double f1,f2,I1,I2;
double sum1,sum2;
cout<<"Distance 1.";
cout<<"\nEnter the feet: ";
cin>>f1;
cout<<"Enter the inch: ";
cin>>I1;
cout<<"Distance 2.";
cout<<"\nEnter the feet: ";
cin>>f2;
cout<<"Enter the inch: ";
cin>>I2;

d1.inputfeet1(f1);
d1.inputfeet2(f2);
d2.inputinch1(I1);
d2.inputinch2(I2);

sum1 = f1 + f2;
d3.sumFeet(sum1);

cout<<"Feet: "<<d3.sumFeet();


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see only minor errors, and they amount to what you would class as bad punctuation in language:)

I have annotated the changes I made ion the code below: mainly you need to indent your code and ensure that you match all open brackets with a closing bracket.

The next thing to do is ensure you have correct return types.  I will post better instructions on the basics tonight when I get home and have the time to post a better tutorial rather than a fix with little instructive value.

I have more correctly indented the .cpp file for distance for you and if you change the code in main.cpp to have

```
sum1 = d3.sumFeet();
```

instead of

```
sum1 = f1 + f2;
d3.sumFeet(sum1);
```

it will work with the following modifications to the remaining code:

`Distance.h` needs to be changed to the following:

```
#ifndef DISTANCE_H
#define DISTANCE_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Distance
{
private:
double feet_1,feet_2;
double inches_1,inches_2;

public:
void inputfeet1(double feet1);
void inputfeet2(double feet2);
void inputinch1(double inch1);
void inputinch2(double inch2);
double sumFeet();
double sumInch();
};

#endif // DISTANCE_H
```

and `Distance.cpp` needs to be amended as follows:

```
void Distance::inputfeet1(double feet1)
{
    if(feet1 < 0)
    {
        cout<<"Cannot be less than zero. Default value of 0 is used.";
    }
    else
    {
        feet_1 = feet1;
    }
}//added this

void Distance::inputfeet2(double feet2)
{
    if(feet2 < 0)
    {
        cout<<"Cannot be less than zero. Default value of 0 is used.";
    }
    else
    {
        feet_2 = feet2;
    }
}//added this too

void Distance::inputinch1(double inch1)
{
    if(inch1 < 0)
    {
        cout<<"Cannot be less than zero. Default value of 0 is being used.";
    }
    else
    {
        inches_1 = inch1;
    }
}

void Distance::inputinch2(double inch2)
{
    if(inch2 < 0)
    {
        cout<<"Cannot be less than zero. Default value of 0 is being used.";
    }
    else
    {
        inches_2 = inch2;
    }
}

double Distance::sumFeet()
{
    return feet_1 + feet_2;
}

double Distance::sumInch()
{
    return inches_1 + inches_2;
}
//removed curly brace here
```

## Tutorial Section

To achieve your aims I would utilise a more object oriented approach, it may seem like overkill for such a simple problem, however the practice will pay off when you eventually start using larger constructs and hierarchies:

**Basic needs:**

- At the basic level you are dealing with `Feet` and `Inches`, we wont bother with them as they are effectively just different names for Doubles in your example code so they are fine as doubles.
- Next we have a distance composed of `Feet` and `Inches`, so we want to do something with that....  (lets call it `DistanceBase`)
- And then we want to do some things with two distances, we will keep the same name as you had earlier and call it `Distance`

So we will have a class called `DistanceBase` composed of `Feet` and `Inches` and a class called `Distance` composed of 2 `DistanceBase`.

### DistanceBase

*Header File:*

As this is a conceptually trivial (not necessarily trivial in the C++ sense *1*) class we can make everything be in the header file, that way it makes the code more portable and transparent, though less secure.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef DISTANCE_BASE_H
#define DISTANCE_BASE_H
/*
    Header file for the DistanceBase class
    #pragma once effectively does the same as the #ifndef loop on compilers that support it.
    Both are included simply as a belt-and-braces approach
*/

//  So that we have a nice simple and clear to read indexing system, lets set up an enum...
enum Units
    {
        FEET = 0,       //  typing Units::FEET will be the same as 0 but more readable and maintainable
        INCHES = 1      //  and likewise Units::INCHES will be the same as 1
    };

class DistanceBase
{
    private:
        double distance[2];     //  we can store the 2 doubles in one array (easier to throw around as a pair then:)

    public:
        void inputFeet(double feet)     {   distance[0] = feet;             }   //  need a way to set the feet
        void inputInches(double inch)   {   distance[1] = inch;             }   //  and inches
        double* getDistance()           {   return distance;                }   //  a way to get both in one go
        double getFeet()                {   return distance[Units::FEET];   }   //  a way to get just the feet
        double getInches()              {   return distance[Units::INCHES]; }   //  a way to get just the inches
};
#endif // DISTANCE_BASE_H
```

Now that we have a class with such a simple level of complexity we can utilise it to create a simple class for your purposes, `Distance`:

### Distance

*Header File*

```
#pragma once
#ifndef DISTANCE_H
#define DISTANCE_H
/*
    Header file for the distance class
*/
#include "DistanceBase.h"

class Distance
{
    private:
        DistanceBase *D1, *D2;      //  2 instances of the DistanceBase class to use together

    public:
        Distance()                      //  this is the constructor, where we can initialise 
        {                               //  the 2 instances we created earlier
            D1 = new DistanceBase();    //  initialise D1
            D2 = new DistanceBase();    //  initialise D2
        }
        DistanceBase* getD1()   {   return D1;                              }   //  this will be the function we use to access all of the properties and members of D1
        DistanceBase* getD2()   {   return D2;                              }   //  this will be the function we use to access all of the properties and members of D2
        double sumFeet()        {   return D1->getFeet()+D2->getFeet();     }   //  add the feet components of D1 and D2
        double sumInches()      {   return D1->getInches()+D2->getInches(); }   //  add the inch components of D1 and D2
};

#endif // DISTANCE_H
```

Again, as this class is very simple (and for ease of posting) I have made everything fit in the header.

Now for the main function, which is now much more simple as the details are take care of by the respective classes:

```
#include "Distance.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Distance *dist = new Distance();            //  instantiate a Distance class as dist
    dist->getD1()->inputFeet(3);                //  set the feet of D1 to 3
    dist->getD2()->inputFeet(7);                //  set the feet component of D2 to 7
    cout << dist->getD1()->getFeet() << endl;   //  check that the values stored match the values input
    cout << dist->getD2()->getFeet() << endl;   //  check that the values stored match the values input
    cout << dist->sumFeet();                    //  add the 2 distances together
    //  now lets use user inputs:
    cout << "Please input the first distance in feet: ";
    //  we can reuse the same variable to save CPU time and memory for all our inputs....
    double tempValue;
    cin >> tempValue;
    dist->getD1()->inputFeet(tempValue);
    cout << "Please input the first distances inch component: ";
    cin >> tempValue;
    dist->getD1()->inputInches(tempValue);
    cout << "Please input the Second distance in feet: ";
    cin >> tempValue;
    dist->getD2()->inputFeet(tempValue);
    cout << "Please input the second distances inch component: ";
    cin >> tempValue;
    dist->getD2()->inputInches(tempValue);
    cout << dist->getD1()->getFeet() << endl;   //  check that the values stored match the values input
    cout << dist->getD2()->getFeet() << endl;   //  check that the values stored match the values input
    cout << dist->sumFeet() << endl;            //  add the 2 distances together
    cout << dist->sumInches() << endl;          //  add the inches components together

    return 0;
}
```

---

### Exploration Points:

Some things you can try out to test yourself:

- separate function definitions and prototypes into `.cpp` and `.h` files
- add functionality to the inches input that turns values greater than `12.0` into feet and inches
- add functionality to change any feet component into feet and inches if there is a decimal point present
- create a `Feet` class and `Inches` class to encapsulate the functionality above
- ensure Feet and Inches are using the most minimal type they can (for example `int` for feet and `float` for inches)
- add error handling to trap things like text input instead of numbers etc.

  Let me know if this all seems OK, or if you need more info, I will happy to help :)

## Notes:

1 Trivial class: in C++ a trivial `class` is one defined (defined with `class`, `struct` or `union`) as both trivially constructible and trivially copyable, which implies that:

- it utilises the implicitly defined default, copy and move constructors, copy and move assignments, and destructor.
- it possesses no virtual members.
- it possesses no non-static data members with brace- or equal- initializers.
- its base class and non-static data members, if it has any, are likewise trivial.

Comment: sorry not had a chance to update this code at home as a tutorial yet, will do as soon as I can

Comment: @DamzZz apologies for the delay, have not had a chance to upload this earlier:)